# R: Using for loop to subset columns from a data.frame with dynamic name

Tags: r, loops, dynamic, dataframe, subset

I want to get three subset data frames from a master data frame. I keep getting error message like this when I run code below.

> Error in `[.data.frame`(x, r, vars, drop = drop) : 
>     undefined columns selected

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(30, 1), nrow = 10, ncol = 26)
z <- c(1, seq(10))

x <- cbind(z, x) #combining 

master = data.frame(x)
start = c(9,14,21) # subset starts from the column ..
end = c(14,21,27) # subset ends with the column ..
grup = c('dm', 'latam', 'ceemea', 'asia')

for (x in 2:4) {
  for (i in start) {
    for (j in end) {
      if(i<j && j-i <=10) {
         assign(paste('ret', grup[x], sep='.'), 
             subset(master, select =  c(1, (i+1):j)))
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Can someone help me out? Please.

My desire output is:

```
ret.latam = master[, c(1, 10:14)] 
ret.ceemea = master[, c(1, 15:21)] 
ret.asia = master[, c(1, 22:27)]
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I want to have sub df like this, ret.latam = master[, c(1, 10:14)], ret.ceemea = master[, c(1, 15:21)], ret.asia = master[, c(1, 22:27)],

Answer (score 0):

Note that `i + 1:j` is not the same as `(i + 1):j`.

The first case is asking to add **i** and a series from **1 to j**, so R will return the series **1 to j**, adding **i** to each of its elements. This results in values outside the number of columns in your master data set.

The second case is asking for a series from the value of adding **i** plus **1** to **j**, that is, the values you want to subset.

Placing the proper parentheses returns your desired output.

```
for (x in 2:4) {
      for (i in start) {
        for (j in end) {
          if(i<j && j-i <=10) {
            assign(paste('ret', grup[x], sep='.'), 
                   subset(master, select =  c(1, (i+1):j)))
          }
        }
      }
    }
```